# Is there a reason not to merge tags foreign-keys and foreign-key-relationship?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I just came across a question with both of the tags [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys) and [foreign-key-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key-relationship) and I think the two tags should be merged into one composite tag, probably called [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys).

As of 2015-04-10 15:15 +00:00:

- [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys) has 4805 questions. Its wiki summary is:

  > A foreign key is a field in a relational table that matches a candidate key of another table. The foreign key can be used to cross-reference tables.
- [foreign-key-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key-relationship) has 1334 questions. Its wiki summary is:

  > In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a referential constraint between two tables.
- 296 questions are tagged with both tags.

Is there a reason why we should not merge the two tags, or make [foreign-key-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key-relationship) a synonym of [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys)?

If the proposal to merge gets community support, the number of questions to be retagged is sufficiently large that the retagging should be automated, not attempted manually.  On the other hand, if they're made synonyms, does that conversion occur automatically?

#### Synonym creation in progress

The [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys) tag already has two synonyms ([foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key) and [fk-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fk-relationship)).  I've added a [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/foreign-keys/synonyms) that [foreign-key-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key-relationship) should be another synonym for it.

***Please*** vote to create the synonym if you have the ability to do so.

Comment: *Breathes fire over the tags, melting them together* COMBININATE! I totally agree, these two tags should be merged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good point. I can't think of any reason these two shouldn't be merged; a "foreign key relationship" necessarily involves foreign keys, so we should merge. The shorter tag is best.

One small point: I think we generally prefer the singular form, so I think the canonical tag should be [foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-key), not [foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foreign-keys). Personally, I'm fine with either.

I say, merge away.

Comment: I was surprised that the singular [tag:foreign-key] tag is a synonym for the plural [tag:foreign-keys] tag, rather than vice versa, but that's the way the system is at the moment.   The consensus is clearly in favour of the merge or synonymization (making up words as we go), but actually getting it done may take a bit of time.  I'm not sure if we can goad suitably empowered people to take decisive action.

Comment: I think the reason [foreign-keys] is preferred is the set-based nature of SQL, a plural comes more naturally (as it is unlikely to ever just have one datum). Though, I have 0 activity in those kind of tags, so I don't actually have an opinion.

Comment: @Joe That's true, but a table may well have only one foreign key. I think [tag:foreign-key] makes more sense, but the first goal obviously needs to be consolidating everything to one tag.